# WCF Consuming Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, wcf

I have a problem with a Published on local network WCF project ,

My WCF project is running and was Published smoothly , but when trying to consume it on ASP.NET web forms project , this error shows up ,

[The Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfqhb.jpg)

Note : I have installed Microsoft Visual studio tools on the local server which holds the IIS which my WCF project is published on.

My Web.Config :

[Web Config Service Model Part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBRRs.jpg)

Comment: Is the webservice set to be in debug mode?

Comment: Yes it is , still not working :(

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of a faulty debugging setting in your VS. Take a look at this. http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/17418.the-famous-system-servicemodel-faultexception1-was-unhandled-by-user-code.aspx

Comment: Thanks for Reply ,

 I Unchecked these two options on my WCF project , republished it , Still the problem is same

Comment: Have you already tried to uncheck the checkbox under Thrown column for row Common Language RunTime exception. This is under Debug Menu -> Exceptions.